# node.js - mean.io implicit/hidden parameters

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

i'm fairly new to node.js so this could potentially a total noob question. Anyway. I discovered the mean.io Project. In the official article-example on [Github](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/articles/server/controllers/articles.js), there is the following method in the article-controller.

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
var article = req.article;

article = _.extend(article, req.body);

article.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.jsonp(500, {
            error: 'Cannot update the article'
        });
    }
    res.jsonp(article);

});
};
```

With a corresponding [route](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/articles/server/routes/articles.js)

```
module.exports = function(Articles, app, auth) {

app.route('/articles')
    .get(articles.all)
    .post(auth.requiresLogin, articles.create);
app.route('/articles/:articleId')
    .get(articles.show)
    .put(auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, articles.update)
    .delete(auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, articles.destroy);

// Finish with setting up the articleId param
app.param('articleId', articles.article);
};
```

So I'm confused. When and where does the route pass the *req/res* parameters to the *articles.update*, or any other *articles* function? Is there some hidden mechanism in node/express/mean I've missed out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, by default when you pass a function as a callback it will receive parameters from the calling function. In this case express handles what will be passed along

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it after Subin's answer. Well, it's a plain old callback handled by express. Silly me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.route('/articles/:articleId')
    .get(articles.show);`

This means express will invoke `articles.show` method with request and response as first two parameters when a GET request comes with matching path
.